# Is there something similar to Dojo GFX in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, dojo

[dojox.gfx](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/gfx.html) (GFX) is a cross-platform vector graphics API that runs with dojo.

It helps to isolate your application from the many native vector graphics implementation differences across all modern Browsers.

From the `dojox/gfx` documentation:

> As of Dojo 1.8, the following native vector graphics engine adaptations are implemented:
>
> - SVG (Firefox 1.5-3.0, Safari(Webkit) 3+, Opera 9+, Chrome 1.0+,
>     iPhone Safari 2.1+
> - VML (IE 6-7-8)
> - Silverlight (wherever it is
>     supported by Microsoft)
> - Canvas (Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+ including
>     iOS Safari 1.0+), Opera 9.0+, Chrome, IE9+
>
> Development of a new experimental renderer which uses SVGWeb is also underway.

Is there anything similar to dojo GFX in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't anything in the native jQuery library. You will have to use additional plugins/libraries to achieve the same level of support. I believe [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) supports both SVG and VML. Alternatively, you can still use the `dojox/gfx` module alongside jQuery. You would have some additional bloat in your JS since a lot of the Dojo library would go unused, but minification will help that (and if you were really ambitious, you *could* strip away the parts you don't need, but that would require a fair amount of digging through the source code).

Comment: Agreed, but it does make sense considering the differences in how jQuery and Dojo are used. jQuery seems to be used more for making standard JavaScript operations easier and more legible (fluent pattern). Whereas Dojo is more suited for rigid client-side architecture design, hence it has more power built in natively. But perhaps that is just my perception.

Comment: "a lot of the Dojo library would go unused" : I don't get that part. Dojo is modular, and only loads the required modules.